# Celery logging to file from inside the Django modules

Tags: python, django, logging, celery

I have the following in my `tasks.py`

```
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
logger = get_task_logger("celery.task")
```

I have setup logging for `celery.task` in my `settings.py` and all the log from my `tasks.py` file are properly logged to file.

I have Django modules. These modules can be called directly from Django or by a Celery task. What I want is, if the module is called by Django, then logs should go to Django log file. If the module is called by a task, the log should go to celery task logger.

Example:

```
# tasks.py

from app.foo import MyFoo

@task(name="bar")
def boo():
    MyFoo.someFoo()

# app.foo.py

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

I want the log messages inside MyFoo to go to celery log when run by a worker task.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to configure loggers separately for Django process and Celery process, as if by definition they run in separate processes.

Actually I am surprised that the log output does not go to a separate log files; thus maybe it would make sense to you expose what kind of logging configurations you have already in-place.

Where Python logging output goes is defined by [logging handlers](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#handler-objects).

Configuring logger for Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/

For Celery, there doesn't seem to be straightforward way to override logging settings. They seem to give a `celery.signals.setup_logging` where you could set a breakpoint, use `logging` API to reconfigure logging handlers to go to a separate log file.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#logging

Alternatively, you can just pull out different `logger` object on a task level. When you execute a task you know whether it is executed from Django (eager) or Celery.

I have never done this myself, but apparently Celery tasks expose the task running context as `self.request` parameter (nothing to do with Python classes).

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#context

So at the beginning of your task function you could switch between the loggers:

```
# Define web_worker_logger
# Define task_logger

@task(name='example')
def moobar():
    logger = web_worker_logger if self.request.is_eager else task_logger
```

Comment: Thanks, this will let me know whether the task is run by a worker or not. This is not what I need. I have updated the question.

Comment: This might be what you need. Because you cannot know if you are running inside Clery or inside Django before you are inside the function. Thus, that is the only point when you can choose which logger to use locally.

Comment: However I suggest you research how to configure Celery loggers. Because Celery worker runs on a separate process, it has its own configuration files where you can configure Python logging handlers. http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#handler-objects

Comment: Updated the answer a bit.